# Drawing a conclusion from equal determinants

Tags: matrices, determinant

If, for two square matrices $A$ and $B$ with equal dimension, $A=B$, then clearly $\det(A)=\det(B)$.
Other than just providing a counter example, why can we not conclude from $\det(C)=\det(D)$ that $C=D$?

Comment: Geometrically, the determinant "can be viewed as the volume scaling factor of the linear transformation described by the matrix" [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant]. There could be linear transformations for which this volume is the same, but the transformations themselves don't have to be equal.

Comment: Any rotation (with respect to origin) in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be represented by a $2 \times 2$ matrix with determinant $1$. There are more than one rotations, this means...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The determinant mapping from $n\times n$ matrices with $n>1$ to $\mathbb R$ is a homomorphism but not an isomorphism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an amusing way to look at this:

suppose that the determinant was injective, then you'd have, with $C:=XY$ and $D:=YX$

$C=XY \mapsto \det\big(XY\big) = \det\big(X\big)\det\big(Y\big) =  \det\big(Y\big)\det\big(X\big)=  \det\big(YX\big)$ but $D=YX \mapsto  \det\big(YX\big) $.  Since we assume the determinant is injective (really an isomrophism) and the selection of $\text{n x n}$ $X$ and $Y$ was arbitrary, we've "proven" that all matrix multiplication must commute (which is the contradiction)

Comment: Ha! Good answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some insight that might be helpful. Geometrically, the determinant can be thought of how much a linear transformation "stretches" the space. Let's consider $\mathbb{R}^2$. If we have the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
2&0\\
0&2
\end{bmatrix}$$
it has a determinant of $4$. The matrix can be interpreted as stretching the $x$ and $y$ axes by a factor of two, which means that an original $1\times 1$ "unit" square becomes a $2\times 2$ square.

Now, you can probably think of many linear transformations that have this property. Indeed, consider the matrix 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
-2&0\\
0&-2
\end{bmatrix}$$
which "flips" the axes and then does the same stretching as the matrix above. The area of a $1\times 1$ square is still going to be $2\times 2$, so the determinant is also $4$.

You might be wondering why 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
-2&0\\
0&2
\end{bmatrix}$$
doesn't work. This is because only one axis is flipped, so the "orientation" of the space is "odd", which means that the determinant should have a negative sign in front of it, giving us $-4$.

This idea generalizes to the change in area of the unit parallelepiped in higher dimensions.

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}4&&0\\0&&1\end{bmatrix}$ too

Answer (score 1):

The space of $n \times n$ real matrices is essentially $\mathbb R^{n^2}$, i.e. $n^2$-tuples of real numbers, just written in a  particular arrangement.  $\det$ thus corresponds to a continuous function from $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ to $\mathbb R$.  There are no one-to-one continuous functions from  $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ to $\mathbb R$ if $n > 1$.

Comment: +1 for the great answer. But still wondering how to prove the last statement of it.

Comment: [Invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain)

Comment: Or, more simply, take two disjoint paths in $\mathbb R^{n \times n}$ from $A$ to $B$ where $\det(A) \ne \det(B)$.  By the intermediate value theorem, if $t$ is between $\det(A)$ and $\det(B)$, on each path there is a matrix with determinant $t$.